# Regex construction to obtain sentences from a text - Python

Tags: python, regex, string

A sentence will be a sequence of characters that:

1. is terminated by (but does not include) the characters ! ? . or the end of the file
2. excludes whitespace on either end, and
3. is not empty

I have a file that contains the following text:

> this is the\nfirst sentence. Isn't\nit? Yes ! !! This \n\nlast bit :) is also a sentence, but \nwithout a terminator other than the end of the file\n

By the above definition, there are four "sentences" in it:

- Sentence 1: `this is the\nfirst sentence`
- Sentence 2: `Isn't\nit`
- Sentence 3: `Yes`
- Sentence 4: `This \n\nlast bit :) is also a sentence, but \nwithout a terminator other than the end of the file`

Notice that:

- The sentences do not include their terminator character.
- The last sentence was not terminated by a character; it finishes with the end of the file.
- Sentences can span multiple lines of the file.

This is what I have at the moment `(.*\n+)` and don't know how to refine it.

Please I need your help for a regex that deconstruct the text into above and return a list. Thanking you in advance for your help.

Comment: Something like https://regex101.com/r/dXXyTt/2

Comment: Are you required to use a regex for this? `nltk` has a solid sentence tokenizer built-in.

Comment: I have only just read about nltk today and is new to me. I'll study it more but the regex will do just now. Thanks to Wiktor, it worked

Comment: @ Wiktor Stribzew Thank you very much. Any chance you could throw in some explanation so that I can repeat this next time. if it's not too much trouble.

Comment: Sorry, I did not get any notification, please do not use spaces between `@` and inside the username.

Answer (score 1):

The following is not something that will work for everyone, but it works for your specific input. You may further tweak this expression:

```
([^!?.]+)[!?.\s]*(?![!?.])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dXXyTt/2).

**Details**:

- `([^!?.]+)` - Capturing group 1 matching 1 or more chars other than `!`, `?`, `.`
- `[!?.\s]*` - 0 or more `!`, `?`, `.`, whitespaces
- `(?![!?.])` - that are not followed with `!`, `?` or `.`.

In Python, you need to use it with `re.findall` that will only fetch the substrings captured with capturing groups:

```
import re
rx = r"([^!?.]+)[!?.\s]*(?![!?.])"
s = "this is the\nfirst sentence. Isn't\nit? Yes ! !! This \n\nlast bit :) is also a sentence, but \nwithout a terminator other than the end of the file\n"
sents = re.findall(rx, s)
print(sents)
# => ['this is the\nfirst sentence', 
      "Isn't\nit", 
      'Yes ', 
      'This \n\nlast bit :) is also a sentence, but \nwithout a terminator other than the end of the file\n'
     ]
```

See [Python demo](http://ideone.com/BLknBd)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
re.split('(\!\s\!+)|\.|\?',s)
['this is the\nfirst sentence', " Isn't\nit", ' Yes ', ' This \n\nlast bit :) is also a sentence, but \nwithout a terminator other than the end of the file\n']
```

Comment: Hi, it returned seven sentences when I ran it